# 0.0111138% of my reputation AWOL - Why?

Tags: support, reputation

Something went awry in the reputation calculation. <del>I want my 10 points back!</del> I'd like to have an explanation for the inconsistency.

Yesterday, I finished the day at

[image: Score at end of 5th May, 89938]

Today, I got another six upvotes (so far), and lost 20 reputation due to two users being removed:

[image: Current reputation and running total for 6th May]

But, in the arithmetic systems I'm used to,

```
89938 + 40 = 89978
```

so 10 points went AWOL, and I wondered why. It seems that the inconsistency is in the calculation for Friday. Originally, it was computed as 245, but now I see

[image: Inconsistent(?) breakdown of 3rd May reputation]

a total of 21 upvotes and three accepts. One answer received an upvote before I deleted it (OP added missing parentheses to the code, so the answer became inapplicable) and appears both with the `+10 upvote` and the `-10 removed`. Fine. That used to mean that in total that answer would be irrelevant for the reputation cap, but in this case, apparently not so, since there is one upvote that didn't earn any reputation on that day.

Have the rules changed? Is it now "delete an upvoted answer and you can't make up for it"?

Or what went wrong here?

Comment: Caching. It is always caching. Looks OK now.

Comment: @Oded No, I received another upvote in the meantime.

Comment: Right you are. Have you looked at the audit page?

Comment: Yes, and triggered a recalc. No effect.

Comment: Hey you are showing your private votes, the answer you downvoted ...... **php transformation..** `:)`

Comment: @exploringnet The answer was "Not an answer" and deleted by moderator soon after, so...

Comment: Wouldn't that be what you'd see if you'd had a post with 10rep from the distant past deleted?

Comment: @Mat More or less, but the Friday breakdown seems inconsistent in itself to me, so that's my first suspect.

Comment: Maybe a couple sock-puppets got merged?